# How can you higher your Ping with the help of Python

Tags: python, windows

My friend asked me as a Joke if I can make a "programm" that will higher your ping.
So that you will have a little delay.
The Problem is that i want to this in python cause i want to learn it.
And I have less to no experience in python.

Everybody that had a clue how python works wanted me to reset the whole program to do that (like `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`). But when I told them that I want to reset or delay the Internet on my computer so if I send a package to the server the answer needs +5sec to get back they had no Idea.

I have no code that could help you help me cause I only have the GUI and some irrelevant and independet other features ready.

So if anyone can show me how this in python could work or give me at least an idea how I could try it, it would be awesome.

Thanks for reading and maybe even helping :D
Leo

Comment: are you using windows or mac?